# Handling multiple document.querySelector results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following basic HTML:

```
<h2>List 1</h2>

<ul class="list-unstyled list">
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="plumespur">plumespur</li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="catflawed">catflawed</li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="drudgemuddy">drudgemuddy</li>                            
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="lungspignut">lungspignut</li>
</ul>

<h2>List 2</h2>

<ul class="list-unstyled list">
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="spongelever">spongelever</li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="stringstick">stringstick</li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="levertorch">levertorch</li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="gravelclock"i>gravelclock</li>
</ul>
```

I have some CSS and JS code which can be used to create "add to favourites" functionality, so a user can click the heart next to each list item , and the list item value is added to LocalStorage.

This is the JS:

```
var ct = 0;
var foo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')) || [];

if (foo) { // count elements
    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        ct ++;
    }
} else {
    ct = 0;
}

var list = document.querySelector('.list');

if (list) {

    document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        var item = e.target;
        var nelly = ct++
        var newCt = "" + nelly + ""; // need to wrap ID in speech marks to get delete element functionality to work
        var findme = foo.findIndex(e => e.name == id);
        if (!id) return;
        if (findme == -1) {
            foo.push({ id: newCt, name: id });
            item.className = 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 fav';
        } else {
            foo.splice(findme, 1)
            item.className = 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nofav';
        }
        localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(foo));
    });

}
```

You can see the code in action on this page:
https://codepen.io/paperknees/pen/pdGKQv

The problem I have is that the Favourites functionality only works in the first `ul` element.

The hearts appear in the second block, but the add to favourites functionality doesn't fire.

Presumably it's because of this section in the JS:

```
var list = document.querySelector('.list');

if (list) {
```

Since there are two UL elements with a class of `list` it means it works for the first block, and ignores any additional blocks.

I wondered how I could change the code so that I can handle having any number of `ul.list` blocks on the page?

I assume I'd need some kind of looping solution to loop through the `document.querySelector` or even use `document.querySelectorAll('ul.list')` but I can't quite get my head about how to revise my code to loop through that.

Comment: Try something like: `var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');` and then check the number of lists available: `if (lists.length > 0) {`. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will only return the first element. There is nothing to loop. You have to use 
[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all your `.list` elements.

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

if (lists.length) {
  lists.forEach(list => {
    list.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (!e.target.id) return;

      var id = e.target.id;
      var item = e.target;
      var nelly = ct++;
      var newCt = "" + nelly + ""; // need to wrap ID in speech marks to get delete element functionality to work
      var findme = foo.findIndex(e => e.name == id);

      if (findme == -1) {
        foo.push({ id: newCt, name: id });
        item.className = 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 fav';
      } else {
        foo.splice(findme, 1)
        item.className = 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nofav';
      }

      localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(foo));
    });
  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOLXMy

Comment: Thank you @Andreas so much for your time, and for helping me fix the issue and improve the code as well :-)